# Tally()ing Multiple Observations In an Entire Data Frame

Tags: r, dataframe, unique, tally

I'm having trouble with figuring out how to deal with a column that features several observations that I would like to tally. For example:

HTML/CSS;Java;JavaScript;Python;SQL

This is one of the cells for a column of a data frame and I'd like to tally the occurrences of each programming language. Is this something that should be tackled with str_detect(), with corpus(), or is there another way I'm not seeing?

My goal is to make each one of these languages (HTML, CSS, Java, JavaScript, Python, SQL, etc...) into a column name with the tally of how many times they occur in this column of the data frame.

I feel like I might've phrased this strangely so let me know if you need any clarification.

Comment: Please add data using `dput` or something that we can copy and use. Also show expected output for the data shared. Read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want a total count of each label, you can use `unnest_longer` and a grouped `count`:

```r
# using @DPH's example data
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(across(PL, strsplit, ";")) %>%
  unnest_longer(PL) %>%
  group_by(PL) %>%
  count()

# A tibble: 6 x 2
# Groups:   PL [6]
  PL             n
  <chr>      <int>
1 HTML/CSS       2
2 Java           1
3 JavaScript     2
4 Python         1
5 R              3
6 SQL            2
```

Comment: Thank you, Andrew. This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

In `tidyverse` you can use `separate_rows` and `count`.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% tidyr::separate_rows(PL, sep = ';') %>% count(PL)
```

In base R, we can split the string on semi-colon and count with `table` :

```
table(unlist(strsplit(df$PL, ';')))
#If you need a dataframe
#stack(table(unlist(strsplit(df$PL, ';'))))
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your problem correctly this would be solution:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# demo data
df <- dplyr::tibble(ID = c("Line 1: ","Line 2:"), 
                    PL = c("HTML/CSS;JavaScript;Python;SQL;R","R;HTML/CSS;Java;JavaScript;SQL;R"))

# calculations
df %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(PLANG = stringr::str_split(PL, ";")) %>% 
  tidyr::unnest(c(PLANG)) %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(ID, PLANG) %>% 
  dplyr::count() %>% 
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = "PLANG", values_from = "n", values_fill = 0)

  ID         `HTML/CSS` JavaScript Python     R   SQL  Java
  <chr>           <int>      <int>  <int> <int> <int> <int>
1 "Line 1: "          1          1      1     1     1     0
2 "Line 2:"           1          1      0     2     1     1
```